# Change single blank lines to double blank lines using awk

Tags: awk

I read [code](http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/faq.html#x1-360003.13) which is trying Change single blank lines to double blank lines using awk. But it did not works for me.

`awk ~NF<2{printf\~\n\~}{print}~ <contour.dat >contour1.dat`

After I read the tutorial of awk, like [NF](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-17), [Escape Sequences](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-28), I still don't have any clue about this code. This is the first time that I use awk.

I run it in bash. It gives me:

`-bash: 2{printf~n~}{print}~: No such file or directory`

What's the correct code should be?

Thank you in advance.

My *Env*

GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

awk version 20070501

Comment: What do you expect to happen for 2 or more consecutive empty lines in the source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk ~NF<2{printf\~\n\~}{print}~
```

I think those tildes should be double-quotes if you run the command in the shell:

```
awk "NF<2{printf\"\n\"}{print}"
```

The error you get is because the shell sees the `<` as a redirection operator, and takes the following part as a file name.

Or better yet, put the awk script in single-quotes so you don't need to escape the quotes within it:

```
awk 'NF<2{printf"\n"}{print}'
```

This would print an extra newline just before any line with less than two fields. But that's not the same as an empty line, lines with just a single word would still get the extra empty line added.

Maybe check if there are exactly zero fields:

```
awk 'NF == 0 {printf "\n"} {print}'
```

or if the line is totally empty:

```
awk '$0 == "" {printf "\n"} {print}'
```

But since the default action is to `print $0` and an empty string is falsy, and `printf "\n"` is pretty much the same as `print` with an empty line, that could be condensed to just:

```
awk '!$0; 1'
```

Comment: _I think those tildes should be double-quotes_ - In the original page `awk` is run from within `gnuplot`, not in a shell.

Comment: @SatoKatsura, FWIW, I can't find any reference to gnuplot taking the ~ specially, and on a simple test, `!echo ~foo bar~` within gnuplot prints tildes, so I'd guess that's just a formatting bug in the source.

Comment: It's a control code in [enhanced mode](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node411.html#enhanced_text)...

Comment: No, but it explains how `~` got there: the page was likely prepared for PostScript (where the `awk` line was emphasized), then somebody thought it would be cool to render it as HTML and put it on the intertubes.

Comment: No chat-capable browser here, sorry...

Comment: Yes, `~` is used in [enhanced text mode](http://www.gnuplotting.org/manpage-gnuplot-4-6/#Q1-1-42) of gnuplot. But I still do not know the exact meaning and usage of it. And When I run the awk code in [gnuplot script of the orgin page](http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/faq.html#x1-360003.13) using `gnuplot script.name`, I got `invalid character \`. `gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 1`. Anyway the solution given by @ikkachu of my problem using awk works. `~` should means double-quotes as @ikkachu wrote, I think. Thanks.

Comment: @NickDong, if that tilde indeed comes from messed-up formatting, the page might contain other messed-up characters too. There's at least some that look like "smart" quotes, and gnuplot might not actually expect them.

Comment: `!` let gnuplot run shell command like `awk`. But gnuplot seems do not know  \ in gnuplot script. It seems that gnuplot do not change ~ to double-quotes when executing the script. So, it seems that ~ is not deployed as smart quotes in my testing script. Well, Shell do not know `~`.

Comment: Now, I know that ~ means overprint, which works in enhance text mode. e.g. **~a{.8-}**  means putting symbol `-` over `a`. `-` will print on the top of `a`, since `8` means 8 times current fontsize. see [Enhanced text mode](http://www.gnuplotting.org/manpage-gnuplot-4-6/#Q1-1-42) . So, tilde in the origin page should be double-quotes. And I change it to double-quotes, it works, no matter running the gnuplot script or running awk code in shell directly.

Comment: @NickDong, the PDF version of the faq seems to have a double-quote. You might want to send a bug report about the HTML version. I thought about doing it, but you might be better equipped to find any other such formatting bugs.